# tomcat says it is started but I cannot connect via web browser

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat

All of a sudden I cannot connect to tomcat through the web browser. Explorer just times out.

But as you can see in the screenshot, it appears tomcat is started.

[image]

I am on:

Microsoft Windows Server 2003.

Apache Tomcat 5.5.25 Server

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access it on http://localhost/? If so, then that'll be you problem. Tomcat listens on port 8080 by default.

Comment: +1 for accuracy.  By default, Tomcat listen on port 8080 for HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a firewall on the machine it would cause IE to time out when trying to connect.

If this is the case you need to make an exception for tomcat, or open the right port.

(Unfortunately it's been a while since I did this on a Windows machine, so I can't tell you the detailed steps to configure the firewall).